Can static-libraries functions get inlined?
Can Static-libraries functions get inlined?
lets say I have these files

main.cpp

#include <lib/header.hpp>
int main() {
    return lib::meaningoflife();
}

lib/header.hpp


namespace lib {
    int meaningoflife();
}

lib/source.cpp

namespace lib {
    int meaningoflife(){ return 42;}
}

Will main just return 42 directly or will it have to call the function? If I make lib a ststic library and link it to my program or does it still require LTO?

you still need LTO, that's why LTO exists.

oh sad, I guess I will use LTP

@user24551355 Stand by for massive intermediate files generated by your build

Of course, for a trivial function like this (undoubtedly simplified) example, its definition could be put in lib/header.hpp and marked inline.

Normally compilers will translate each translation unit, i.e. each .cpp file, individually. They optimize only with respect to what they can see in each such unit.
When the resulting object files are later linked together, in whatever form, then no further optimizations will happen. The linking process is rather dumb and will only fill out call sites of functions or references to objects with corresponding addresses from the (other) object files. Inlining won't happen at this stage.
However, compilers nowadays support a compilation mode called link-time optimization (LTO), which permits optimizations to be also applied during the linking process across translation units. To do this the compiler only compiles translation units into an intermediate representation instead of an object file and the linker, when attempting to link the intermediate files, will call back into the compiler to let it optimize and fully translate to machine code while seeing the whole (or at least most of the) program's code.
If you enable LTO, then the compiler will likely be able to inline the function. Otherwise not.
